# Reduce array list, to set of common paths

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to reduce a list to a shorter list, of just common filesystem paths. Trying to find all the common grandparents, and put only those in the final list. Here is the *goal*: **The goal is that we must eliminate all directories in the list for which there is a parent directory in the list.**

A better way to phrase that might be:
**The goal is that we must eliminate all paths in the list for which there is a parent directory of that path in the list.**

Say I have this input and expected output:

```
const input = [
  "/home/oleg/WebstormProjects/oresoftware/r2g",
  "/home/oleg/WebstormProjects/oresoftware/sumanjs/suman",
  "/home/oleg/WebstormProjects/oresoftware/sumanjs",
  "/home/oleg/WebstormProjects/oresoftware/sumanjs/suman-types",
  "/home/oleg/WebstormProjects/oresoftware/sumanjs/suman-watch"
];

const output = [
  "/home/oleg/WebstormProjects/oresoftware/r2g",
  "/home/oleg/WebstormProjects/oresoftware/sumanjs",
];

const getReducedList = function (input) {

  return input
  .sort((a, b) => (a.length - b.length))
  .reduce((a, b) => {

    // console.log('a:', a, 'b:', b);

    const s = !a.some(v => {
      return b.startsWith(v);
    });

    if (s) {
      a.push(b);
    }

    return a;

  }, []);

};

console.log(getReducedList(input));
```

that `getReducedList` function seems to work with our first test case, 5 is reduced to 2. **But, if we add a second test case, here is where things get weird:**

If I *remove an item from the original list* and change it to this list of 4:

```
const input = [
  "/home/oleg/WebstormProjects/oresoftware/r2g",
  "/home/oleg/WebstormProjects/oresoftware/sumanjs/suman",
  "/home/oleg/WebstormProjects/oresoftware/sumanjs/suman-types",
  "/home/oleg/WebstormProjects/oresoftware/sumanjs/suman-watch"
];
```

then I would expect to get this output (the same list of 4):

```
const output = [
  "/home/oleg/WebstormProjects/oresoftware/r2g",
  "/home/oleg/WebstormProjects/oresoftware/sumanjs/suman",
  "/home/oleg/WebstormProjects/oresoftware/sumanjs/suman-types",
  "/home/oleg/WebstormProjects/oresoftware/sumanjs/suman-watch"
];
```

the reason why I would expect/desire the same list of 4, is because no item in the list has a parent directory elsewhere in the list. But I actually get this output, a list of 2, which is incorrect:

```
const output =  [ 
   '/home/oleg/WebstormProjects/oresoftware/r2g',
   '/home/oleg/WebstormProjects/oresoftware/sumanjs/suman' 
];
```

does anyone know how I can fix this to get the expected result instead? An answer needs to satisfy both test cases.

To make it perfectly clear, if you add `"/home/oleg"` to the original list, then `"/home/oleg"` should be the only entry in the output.

Comment: I think the problem stems from the fact that `"/home/oleg/WebstormProjects/oresoftware/sumanjs/suman-types"` startsWith `"/home/oleg/WebstormProjects/oresoftware/sumanjs/suman"` but that `"/home/oleg/WebstormProjects/oresoftware/sumanjs/suman"` is not a parent directory of the first.

Comment: Maybe, add checking of a divider '/' to getReducedList

Comment: @Jarvis yes you were probably right, if only you had written more about that idea :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do this with a very simple recursive function. You simply sort by length, then recursively pop the shortest, add it to the results, filter the array with that, recurse:

```js
const input = [
    "/home/oleg/WebstormProjects/oresoftware/r2g",
    "/home/oleg/WebstormProjects/oresoftware/sumanjs/suman",
    "/home/oleg/WebstormProjects/oresoftware/sumanjs",
    "/home/oleg/WebstormProjects/oresoftware/sumanjs/suman-types",
    "/home/oleg/WebstormProjects/oresoftware/sumanjs/suman-watch"
  ];
  
input.sort((a,b) => b.length - a.length)
function getPrefixes(list, res =[]) {
    if (list.length < 1) return res
    let next = list.pop()
    res.push(next)
    return getPrefixes(list.filter(u => !u.startsWith(next + '/')), res)

}
console.log(getPrefixes(input))
```

Comment: this seems to work for a variety of tests, nice work, the proper answer to this question was way more difficult than I expected. Most  of the battle is understanding what the OP wanted I think..

Comment: Maybe not the most efficient answer, but the only one that's correct so far.

Comment: Indeed, the question was lacking information. @OlegzandrDenman, did you check my latest update (of 6 minutes ago)?

Comment: can you explain why you add the slash '/'?

Comment: @OlegzandrDenman You need the slash otherwise a path ending in `suman` filters paths like `suman-types`

Comment: And yes there may be more efficient ways. In the worst case this will run in quadratic time. But the trade off is simplicity.

Comment: @MarkMeyer I actually think the only thing that needs to change in the OP is adding the '/', so it should be `return b.startsWith(v + '/');`...lol that small change made a big difference.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like we only needed to change one line. Here is the original:

```
const getReducedList = function (input) {

  return input
  .sort((a, b) => (a.length - b.length))
  .reduce((a, b) => {

    const s = !a.some(v => {
      return b.startsWith(v);
    });

    if (s) {
      a.push(b);
    }

    return a;

  }, []);

};
```

we need to change the one line to this instead:

```
return b.startsWith(v + '/');
```

Comment: Quite right! Just one remark: the `some` makes it inefficient on long input arrays.

Comment: I actually don't understand why people ask such  interesting questions instead of keeping joy for themselves. Don't get me wrong :)

Comment: haha yeah I seriously could not figure it out, I got stuck in a mental loop, thanks anyway

Comment: @trincot you think a regular for loop instead of `Array.prototype.some` is better? I think it's pretty cheap either way, I guess I would only worry if it were greater than O(n)

Comment: A regular loop would run a bit faster, but not with a different time complexity. However, a set lookup (hash) runs in O(1) time, so that *does* make a difference.

Comment: @trincot yeah but you'd have to replace  `b.startsWith(v);` with something else. The `startsWith` technique would mean you'd have to iterate on all the keys of the hash, which would make it O(n) again.

Comment: Indeed and that is why my answer does not use `startsWith`.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a slash for look up and pop the last value if found in next element.

This proposal uses a sorted list by value, not by lenght of the string, because it needs a sorted list for compairing the next element.

```js
function uniqueFolder(array) {
    return array
        .sort()
        .reduce((a, b) => {
            if (b.startsWith(a[a.length - 1] + '/')) {
                a.pop();
            }
            a.push(b);
            return a;
        }, []);
}

function commonPath(array) {
    return array
        .sort()
        .reduce((a, b) => {
            if (!b.includes(a[a.length - 1])) {
                a.push(b);
            }
            return a;
        }, []);
}

const input = [ "/home/oleg/WebstormProjects/oresoftware/r2g", "/home/oleg/WebstormProjects/oresoftware/sumanjs/suman", "/home/oleg/WebstormProjects/oresoftware/sumanjs", "/home/oleg/WebstormProjects/oresoftware/sumanjs/suman-types", "/home/oleg/WebstormProjects/oresoftware/sumanjs/suman-watch"];

console.log(uniqueFolder(input));
console.log(commonPath(input));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use node's `path` module

```
const path = require('path');
const input = [
  '/home/oleg/WebstormProjects/oresoftware/r2g',
  '/home/oleg/WebstormProjects/oresoftware/sumanjs/suman',
  '/home/oleg/WebstormProjects/oresoftware/sumanjs',
  '/home/oleg/WebstormProjects/oresoftware/sumanjs/suman-types',
  '/home/oleg/WebstormProjects/oresoftware/sumanjs/suman-watch'
];

const s = new Set();
const out = [];
input.forEach(e => {
  let p = path.dirname(e);
  if (! s.has(p)) {
    s.add(p);
    out.push(e);
  }
});

console.log(out);
```

The forEach could obviously replaced by reduce if you want to...

Comment: nah I don't this will work, there is more to the problem unfortunately

Comment: Too bad you didn't post the real problem.. @OlegzandrDenman ; for the code in the question it'll work perfectly fine

Comment: When I first posted the OP, there were two test cases to be met, I updated the OP with the goal, which is: *we must eliminate all paths in the list for which there is a parent directory of that path in the list*

Answer (score 0):

If you can use sets from es6 then you can simply sort with respect to directory length and keep pushing to a set.

Answer (score 0):

You need to avoid matches when the next value does not have its *last* forward slash following the previous value.

```js
const input = [
  "/home/oleg/WebstormProjects/oresoftware/r2g",
  "/home/oleg/WebstormProjects/oresoftware/sumanjs/suman",
  "/home/oleg/WebstormProjects/oresoftware/sumanjs",
  "/home/oleg/WebstormProjects/oresoftware/sumanjs/suman-types",
  "/home/oleg/WebstormProjects/oresoftware/sumanjs/suman-watch"
];

const getReducedList = (set => input => input.filter(b => 
     !set.has(b.substr(0, b.lastIndexOf("/")))))(new Set(input));

console.log(getReducedList(input));
```

The logic is that it puts all paths in a set, and then checks for each path whether its parent is in the set. A path's parent is the path that has all characters up to, and excluding, the final `/`.

Removing the second entry from the input will not change the output. `suman` is treated the same way as `suman-types` and `suman-watch`.

Here is a more verbose, ES5 version (replacing the `Set` with a plain object):

```js
const input = [
  "/home/oleg/WebstormProjects/oresoftware/r2g",
  "/home/oleg/WebstormProjects/oresoftware/sumanjs/suman",
  "/home/oleg/WebstormProjects/oresoftware/sumanjs",
  "/home/oleg/WebstormProjects/oresoftware/sumanjs/suman-types",
  "/home/oleg/WebstormProjects/oresoftware/sumanjs/suman-watch"
];

function getReducedList(input) {
    var hash = {};
    input.forEach(function(path) {
        hash[path] = true;
    });
    return input.filter(function (b) {
        return !hash[b.substr(0, b.lastIndexOf("/"))];
    }, []);
}

console.log(getReducedList(input));
```

Comment: yes this satisfies both test cases, let me think about how it works now..

Comment: can you write an unfancy version of the function? Keep the fancy version, but write a non-fancy one too?

Comment: Added a more verbose ES5 version.

Comment: If I add `"/home/oleg/WebstormProjects/oresoftware"` to the input, shouldn't I expect that to be the only output?

Comment: @MarkMeyer yes you are correct, I was just going to comment about that. The best answer will be result in the thing that Mark just said.

Comment: @Hikmat Gurbanli answer passes the test that Mark mentioned...so I accepted that answer

Comment: Updated my answer to fit that requirement.

Answer (score 0):

It works without sort though has other drawbacks.

Edit: Had to add sort to work properly

```js
const input = [
  "/home/oleg/WebstormProjects/oresoftware/r2g",
  "/home/oleg/WebstormProjects/oresoftware/sumanjs/suman",
  "/home/oleg/WebstormProjects/oresoftware/sumanjs",
  "/home/oleg/WebstormProjects/oresoftware/sumanjs/suman-types",
  "/home/oleg/WebstormProjects/oresoftware/sumanjs/suman-watch"
];

const input2 = [
  "/home/oleg/WebstormProjects/oresoftware",
  "/home/oleg/WebstormProjects/oresoftware/r2g",
  "/home/oleg/WebstormProjects/oresoftware/sumanjs/suman",
  "/home/oleg/WebstormProjects/oresoftware/sumanjs/suman-types",
  "/home/oleg/WebstormProjects/oresoftware/sumanjs/suman-watch"
];

function getParents(input) {
  return input.sort((a, b) => a.length - b.length)
  .reduce((acc, a) => {
    const index = acc.findIndex(b => b.startsWith(a) || a.startsWith(b));
    const slashDiff = index > 0 ? a.split('/').length === acc[index].split('/').length : false;
    if (index === -1 || slashDiff) {
      return [...acc, a];
    }
    acc.splice(index, 1, a.length < acc[index].length ? a : acc[index])

    return acc;
  }, []);

}

console.log(getParents(input));
console.log(getParents(input2));
```

Comment: yes this output is correct, kudos for organizing your answer btw

Comment: this works, and when you add `"/home/oleg/WebstormProjects/oresoftware"` to the list, that should be the only item in the output, and your code satisfies that too. Now if I could just figure out how this works...lulz

Comment: You are really smart to figure out what I was looking for and get it right, nice job

Comment: It doesn't unfortunately )) if you add it to the end of the list

Comment: ahh, let me check

Comment: added sort, it works now I think, but it could be optimized

Answer (score 0):

```js
const input = [
  "/home/oleg/WebstormProjects/oresoftware/r2g",
  "/home/oleg/WebstormProjects/oresoftware/sumanjs/suman",
  "/home/oleg/WebstormProjects/oresoftware/sumanjs",
  "/home/oleg/WebstormProjects/oresoftware/sumanjs/suman-types",
  "/home/oleg/WebstormProjects/oresoftware/sumanjs/suman-watch",
  "/home/oleg/WebstormProjects/oresoftware/sumanjs/suman-types-blabla",

];

let ouput = input.sort().reduce((a, c)=> {
let d = true;
for (let j =0; j< a.length; j++){
  if(c.startsWith(a[j]+'/')) {
  d=false;
  break;}
}
if (d) a.push(c);
return a;
},[]);

console.log(ouput);
```